# Does the value counts of 1's and 0's in my dataframe while using a Decision Tree Classifier matters?

Tags: python, machine-learning

I am using a Decision Tree Classifier and in the data, the target column is 'TARGET' which consists of 0's and 1's
`TARGET 0         282686 1          24825 dtype: int64`
and after training on 0.75 of the whole data it is giving all the output as 0 and the accuracy_score for training, validation, test set is >0.90.

Comment: The values of target are fine. You have imbalanced data, and sampling method for train test sets matters a lot. So in your data ~91 % of obs. has target of 0, and if your model predicts only 0s, then it will be correct for the same percentage of times. Check out some articles on dealing with imbalanced data and sampling methods.

Comment: thanks mark , the problem was due to imbalanced data .

Comment: btw took some help from  [link](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2020/07/10-techniques-to-deal-with-class-imbalance-in-machine-learning/#h2_14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Evaluation:**

The **test set** should produce accuracy less than your **training set**. The training set is said to be trained with everything it knows and test doesn't know the patterns in training data.
The simple evaluation method is to find train and test accuracy and compare them.

**Results**

1. if `train accuracy < test accuracy` there is a problem check everything. The problem would mostly fall on the train test split. Using [**stratification method**](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) will do some good in this or try some other subset of data
2. if `train accuracy > test accuracy` then almost it is right, you can work on optimizing it.